# python nested loop using files and if condition not working

Tags: python, file, for-loop

I have:

```
master = open('master.txt', 'r')
transaction = open('transaction.txt', 'r')

master_list = []
employee_list = []


    for line in master:
        # split the line
        record = line.split(',')
        # extract id from record
        emp_id = record[0]
        # add id to list
        employee_list.append(emp_id)

        for li in transaction:
            # split the line
            rec = li.split(',')
            i_d = rec[3]
            print(i_d)
```

This works as expected and outputs

```
001
001
001
001
001
002
002
002
002
002
003
003
003
003
003
004
004
004
004
004
005
005
005
005
005
```

but if I use an if statement in the nested loop like this:

```
for li in transaction_file:
            # split the line
            rec = li.split(',')
            i_d = rec[3]
            if i_d == emp_id:
                print(emp_id)
```

I only get 001 001 001 001 001

why is that?

Comment: @akonsu are you trolling, bro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never rewind your transaction file; you go through it once during the first cycle of your master loop.

The structure you have may not be the best possible, but:

```
for line in master:
    # split the line
    record = line.split(',')
    # extract id from record
    emp_id = record[0]
    # add id to list
    employee_list.append(emp_id)

    transaction.seek(0)
    for li in transaction:
        # split the line
        rec = li.split(',')
        i_d = rec[3]
        print(i_d)
```

The `transaction.seek(0)` will rewind you back to the beginning of the file (move the reading position to the start of the file) every time before you iterate through it.